# Partially lookup different tables or workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 different workbooks or tables

**Table 1**

| **Name** | **Code** |
| --- | --- |
| shoe | shoe |
| slip on | shoe |
| slip | apparel |

**table 2**

| **TAG** |
| --- |
| blue color cut Shoe |
| red color canvas shoe |
| green see through slip on |
| apparel inner slip |
| safari high heel |

**needed output**

| **TAG** | **Code** |
| --- | --- |
| blue color cut Shoe | shoe |
| red color canvas shoe | shoe |
| green see through slip on | shoe |
| apparel inner slip | apparel |
| safari high heel | N/A |

I tried using partial vlookup with 'name' from table 1 as lookup value against TAG in table 2 but unable to get the desired o/p
I have also tired using
Index match (=INDEX('table 1'!A:A,MATCH("*"&'table 1'!A2&"*",'table 2'!A:A,0))) and
xlookup (=XLOOKUP("*"&'table 1'!A2&"*",'table 2'!A:A,'table 1'!A:A,0,1,2)) and
(=XLOOKUP("*"&'table 1'!A2&"*",'table 2'!A:A,'table 1'!B:B))

Tried this also (=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('table 1'!A:A,'table 2'!A2)),'table 1'!A:A))

Answer (score 0):

I think this formula is working. Just make sure your table 1 has the more specific item (slip on) before the less specific one (slip)

`=INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH(1,SEARCH($A$1:$A$3,E1)/SEARCH($A$1:$A$3,E1),0))`

[image]